# Google App Engine PHP Message Service - From name support

Tags: php, google-app-engine, email

I need set sender name, but I have errors when I used this:

```
$mail=new \google\appengine\api\mail\Message();
$mail->setSender("Sender Name <email@address.com>");
```

same problem, if I tried modify headers:

```
$mail->addHeader("From", "Sender Name <email@address.com>");
```

Somebody who solved this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue in GAE PHP, you can track it at https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10153